# What is the integration representation of this function notation?

Tags: calculus, integration

Like this representation.

$\int f'(x) dx = f(x) + C$

what is the representation for ?

$\int f'(x^2) dx = ?$

is $xf'(x^2)+C$ can be a right answer ?

Comment: No, not in general. You could try integration by parts though...

Answer (score 4):

There is no general way to do it. If there were, then setting $f(x) = -e^{-x}$, we could easily use the method to find a representation for
$$
\int e^{-x^2}dx
$$
which is famously impossible.

Now, $\int xf'(x^2)dx$, on the other hand, is relatively simple with some substitution. Setting $u = x^2$, which gives $du = 2x\,dx$, we get
$$
\int xf'(x^2)dx = \int \frac12f'(u)du = \frac12f(u) + C = \frac12f(x^2) + C
$$

Comment: is $xf'(x^2) + C$ can be a right answer ?

Comment: @user292174 What do you mean? A right answer for what?